# Как вы тестируете верстку и JS на кроссбраузерность?

Tags: кроссбраузерность, вёрстка, тестирование, javascript

Знаю про [Adobe Browser Labs](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html), IETester, который работает криво. Пока не вижу иного выхода, кроме как держать армию виртуалок под разные браузеры.

Comment: Армия портативных версий браузеров не подходит?)

Comment: Не помню точных причин почему отказался от этого варианта, буду благодарен если подкинете ссылку на источник, откуда можно скачать годные незавирусованные рабочие версии.

Answer (score 3):

1. Для первой отладки используется армия своих браузеров. (Альфа версия)
2. Когда все запилено, кладем сие творение mysite.com/tests/ ну или еще куда нибудь.
3. Просим в аське или по почте своих модераторов, друзей и тд. посидеть на новой версии, поскольку всех разные браузеры, разрещение экрана, настройки и тд. (Бета версия)
4. Получаем бурю негодований и скриншотов на почту.
5. Фиксим баги и заливаем готовый вариант на сайте. (Релиз)
6. ???????
7. PROFIT!!!

Ни одна программа не протестит так как это могут сделать твои друзья и постоянные поситители сайта. Ну если надо осла, то устанавливаем Ietester и не плохо будет попросить друзей тоже зайти с ослика. Если проект очень маленький на нем сидит 3,5 анонимуса, то лучше будет на ходу совместно пилить дизайн.

Comment: При ИеТестер я написал специально. Это плохой инструмент.

Answer (score 2):

Пользуюсь этим инструментом. Делает скриншоты сайта в разных браузерах: http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score -1):

Вообще лучше всего для начала проверить верстку вот тут: http://validator.w3.org/
После этого, ничего лучше нет, чем проверить на всех современных браузерах, а позже на IETester

Comment: Почему вы все так поклоняетесь этому валидатору? Он вообще ничего не дает, никаких плюсов. Он не сделает за вас красивую верстку, он не узнает почему блок стоит ниже и тому подобное. Самый верный способ - это набор браузеров.

Comment: Я написал про набор браузеров! Однако, этот валидатор дает эффекты. Порой мы допускаем мелкие и непростительные ошибки, которые с легкостью находит данный валидатор, и ваш негатив по поводу этого валидатора - моветон. А давай сделаем, лишь бы смотрелось нормально. Поисковики отчасти тоже оценивают качество верстки и косячность.

Comment: Достаточно знать, каким способом поисковик кушает контент и замороки по поводу валидатора отпадут навсегда.

Comment: Каждый поисковик смотрит по своему, у каждого свои алгоритмы. Все же, "лучше", если все изначально правильно. По крайней мере на западе с этим все качественно. Соглашусь, что не на все ошибки стоит смотреть, но отчасти он позволяет увидеть свои "косяки" ))

Comment: Валидатор не творит чудеса, мой вопрос касается больше отображения сайта и тестирования JS. IETester косячит и с тем и с другим.

Comment: @Лисенок Валидатор порой помогает. Нельзя отрицать сервис, который используют специалисты по всему миру.

Comment: Несколько примеров валидации и мнение Артемия Лебедева:
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Result:  23 Errors, 3 warning(s)

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.artlebedev.ru%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3

Result:  1 Error, 3 warning(s)
Line 1, Column 1: no document type declaration; will parse without validation 
<N.B.>Лучший валидатор - это браузер</N.B.>

Comment: В чем-то вы все правы, но не совсем поняли то, что я хочу донести. Бывает возникают ошибки, которые на первый взгляд не видны, или не видны в конкретном браузере. Не стоит так критично относится к валидатору.

Comment: То, что можно написать фигню, и она, благодаря толерантности браузеров, даже будет работать — не повод писать фигню.

Но кроссбраузерности чистый код помогает мало. Главная проблема кроссбраузерности  — это не что лично верстала пишет говнокод. Это то, что браузеры, иногда, трактуют даже самый валиднй код по-разному.